# Asterisk php dial

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami

I need connect 2 users in asterisk. What best choise for this ?AGI or PAMI ?now i test PAGI
and my extension.conf 
some like this

```
exten => 1,1,AGI(/var/tmp/quickstart/run.sh)
exten => 1,n,Hangup
```

and in main method i make test call ,like

```
  $result = $client->dial("SIP/demo-alice");
    if ($result->isAnswer()) {
        $this->log("ANSWERIN");
        $this->log($clid);
    }
```

But dial in php script ,its blocking application.
But dial from php script is blocking all script.
And when a lot of connection happen, server will be overloaded. What is the best choice to connect 2 sip users?AGI or AMI?

Answer (score 0):

You need read book like ORelly's "Asterisk the Future of telephony"

Short answer: you not need use both. You have use dialplan.

Comment: Thnx.Now use AGI and in php script,just check username.And call user from dialplan